# Split values from column based on the name of the column

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic, iteration

I work with QGIS and PostgreSQL with PostGIS. I need help with dynamic queries for PostgreSQL.

Information is structured in tables that contain votes for parties, and other types of information like geographic area or election date.

Some columns contains values that have to be splitted among several parties.  For example, we can have a column with name "PartyA_PartyB" and a value of 10, and it should be splitted 5 votes to PartyA and 5 votes to PartyB.  Additionally we will have independent columns for PartyA and PartyB (separated), so we need to compute a column where we allocate the original PartyA + PartyA_PartyB/2.

So for example for the given the tables “Election Results” and "Parties":

```
create table election_results ("Country" text,  "PartyA" text,  "PartyB" text,  "PartyC" text, "PartyA_PartyB" text);
insert into election_results
VALUES
  ('Argentina', 100, 10, 20, 2),
  ('Uruguay', 3, 5, 1, 0),
  ('Chile', 40, 200, 50, 10)
;


create table parties (party text);
insert into parties
VALUES
  ('PartyA'),
  ('PartyB'),
  ('PartyC'),
  ('PartyD'),
  ('PartyE')
;
```

I need to create a new table with a column where 'new' PartyA = PartyA + PartyA_PartyB/2  and 'new' PartyB = PartyB + PartyA_PartyB/2

So with previous data desired result is:

| Country | PartyA | PartyB | PartyC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Argentina | 101 | 11 | 20 |
| Uruguay | 3 | 5 | 1 |
| Chile | 45 | 205 | 50 |

In all cases the special characters that separates the names to be splitted is '_'.

We can have n parties in the column names (for example PartyA_PartyB_PartyD_PartyE).  Votes have to be splitted among the n parties.

With my limited understanding I think iterate over the columns could be a solution, look for the '_' character and recalculate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: Please store your values not as text but as a numeric type.

- [demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/r4Fe5fHl) (2 joined colums)
- [demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rAqM7xTk) (additional 3 joined columns)

1. Create your new table:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE parties (
        "Country" text,  
        "PartyA" numeric,  
        "PartyB" numeric,  
        "PartyC" numeric
   );
   ```
2. Copy values for the "single" columns:

   ```
   INSERT INTO parties

   SELECT "Country", "PartyA", "PartyB", "PartyC"
   FROM election_results;
   ```
3. Update the columns with a function

   ```
   SELECT * FROM split_and_update_parties();
   ```

The function could look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_and_update_parties()
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
    i record;
    j text;
    n integer;
BEGIN 
  FOR i in 
     
      SELECT                                       
           column_name,                                  -- 1
           string_to_array(column_name, '_')             -- 2
       FROM information_schema.columns
       WHERE table_name   = 'election_results'
           AND column_name ~ 'Party'     
     
   LOOP
       n = cardinality(i.string_to_array);               -- 3
       IF n > 1 THEN
           FOREACH j in array i.string_to_array LOOP
            
               EXECUTE format('
         
                   UPDATE parties p                      -- 4
                   SET %I = p.%I + s.val / %s
                   FROM (
                       SELECT %I as val, "Country"
                       FROM election_results
                   ) s
                   WHERE p."Country" = s."Country"
          
               ', j, j, n, i.column_name);

           END LOOP;
       END IF;
   END LOOP;

END
$func$;
```

Explanation:

1. Fetch column names from internal information schema
2. Immediately split the names and convert them into arrays
3. Count the elements of the arrays to know the divider needed furtherly in the calculation
4. Loop through all these multiple-party-arrays/columns (with more than 1 element), fetch the original values from the `election_results` table and update the single-party-columns in the new table

Comment: I appreciate your help.  In step 2, please help me to know how to retrieve the list of parties from table "parties", not writing them manually in the query.  Please note that "parties" table has only one column ('party').

Comment: I am nit even sure why you have such table list. You get all thr information about the columns from the column headers of your first table. There columns with names "PartyA" to "PartyE" are already given, aren't they? So, I fetch dem from the information schema instead of your party table.

Comment: Thanks.  The list of parties can get large and change in the future.  Also I need to discard other columns in the "election_results" table, that contain different kind of data.